# How to add message collectors to this code discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to add a message collector that looks for if either a, b or c and sends preset message to a preset channel depending on the choices. Like if you chose A it would send an embed message to #responses saying your username and that you chose choice A. How would I do this?

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ac',
    description: "help command",
    async execute(message,args, discord) {
        message.channel.send('What position would you like to register for\na.\nb.\nc.')
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before all I recommend you to check [The collectors guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-message-collector)
But here is a simple example I did like the guide

```js
// `m` is a message object that will be passed through the filter function
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id; //if the one who sent respond is same as who executed the command
//here we create collector
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
//The event when collector 'collects' a message
collector.on('collect', async msg=>{
   if(msg.content === "a"){
       //do something
   }
   if(msg.content === "b"){
       //do another thing
   }
});
```